# Among Vs between

Tags: american-english, british-english, spoken-english, between-among

I saw a sentence, "Between videos games, television, and the internet, kids these days are spoilt for choice when it comes to their entertainment".
We can't use 'between' for more than two entities so it is wrong here. So my question is that can we use 'among' for non living things(in this case)?

Answer (score 2):

[The Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/why-would-anyone-use-the-chicago-manual-of-style) describes these as one-to-one relationships. Sometimes they are between two items, groups, or people, as in these examples:

- Choose **between** Squiggly and Aardvark.
- Let's keep this **between** you and me.

Other times they can be between more than two items, groups, or people as in these examples:

- The negotiations **between** the cheerleaders, the dance squad, and the
  flag team were going well despite the confetti incident.
- The differences **between** English, Chinese, and Arabic are significant.

On the other hand, you use among when you are talking about things that aren't distinct items or individuals. For example, if you were talking about colleges collectively you could say, "She chose among the Ivy League schools."

If you are talking about a group of people, you also use among:

- Fear spread **among** the hostages.
- The scandal caused a division **among** the fans.
- Squiggly and Aardvark are **among** the residents featured in the
  newsletter.

See original post here: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/between-versus-among